# Extract JSON data from feed using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to parse a JSON API, however, I can't figure out how to parse the response data from Alamofire.

When I try to loop through the fetched data, XCode gives me "Segmentation Fault: 11" error.

Here is my current code:

```
var tableData:NSArray // I have tried several variable types, NSDictionary, String etc.
```

--

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.getJsonData()
}

func getJsonData() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://hotell.difi.no/api/json/mattilsynet/smilefjes/tilsyn", parameters: [:])
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                // print("JSON: \(response.result)")

                for entry in JSON["entries"] {
                    print("\(entry)") // this is where everything crashes
                }


            }

            self.doTableRefresh()
    }
}

func doTableRefresh() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return
    })
}
```

What is the correct data format for this JSON result: https://hotell.difi.no/api/json/mattilsynet/smilefjes/tilsyn ? And how do I take the data and populate the tableview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the response to NSDictionary and NSArray:

```
func getJsonData() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://hotell.difi.no/api/json/mattilsynet/smilefjes/tilsyn", parameters: [:])
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary{

                if let entries = JSON["entries"] as? NSArray{

                    for entry in entries {

                        if let entry = entry as? NSDictionary {

                            for (key, value) in entry {
                                print("\(key) - \(value)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type of your expected value (With [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)):

```
for entry in JSON["entries"] { // Here
    print(entry.stringValue)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. However, Xcode says "Value of optional type 'AnyObject?!' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Comment: oops, sorry my bad ! Too quick

Comment: The segmentation fault error is back. This error is so cryptic. :O

Comment: @Ronny-AndréBendiksen I just realized you don't use SwiftyJSON, exact? Just Alamofire? I think Thomas assumes you're using SwiftyJSON.

Comment: True, I don't. Installed and imported now, but still same segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

Without using SwiftyJSON, the idea is to know the right type for each object and successfully downcast.

`response.result.value` is a dictionary: `[String:AnyObject]`, and the content of `json["entries"]` is an array of dictionaries: `[[String:AnyObject]]`. Etc.

Example:

```
func getJsonData() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://hotell.difi.no/api/json/mattilsynet/smilefjes/tilsyn", parameters: [:])
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let json = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                if let entries = json["entries"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                    for entry in entries {
                        print(entry) // each entry is a dictionary of type [String:AnyObject]
                    }
                    // example of accessing an entry:
                    if let firstEntry = entries.first, value = firstEntry["adrlinje1"] as? String {
                        print(value) // "Christian IV gate 3"
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```